# Move file after changing name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have written a script that attaches a timestamp to a list of files, say

```
`mv $THELINE $stamp"_"$THELINE`
```

Where $stamp is variable containing that timestamp and $THELINE is the looping variable.

Now what I want to accomplish is that as soon as the filename is modified, I want to move that file(whose name has just been modified) to another location.

How may I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put the command directly after, Bash will wait until the first `mv`
finishes.

```
mv "$THELINE" "$stamp"_"$THELINE"
mv "$_" another-location
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it with one single command

```
mv "$THELINE" "another-location/${stamp}_${THELINE}"
```